# Remove the numbers and the period after numbers in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a mock-up dataframe representing some of the confidential data I have and it looks like this:

```
Name                      Value
1. AaaaBaCCCaaa.x         1
2. AbbAbbKalllNBN.y       2
3. CCCdddEfffFg.x         8
4. ZZZtTThGGtGGGG.y       1
...
9. AAAHHHhhhhIIIIII.x     2
10. RRRRmmmmJJJJJJJ.y     3
11. MMMMMnnnnNNNNrrrr.x   4
...
```

What's important to notice here is that the `Name` variable contains ordinal numbers (e.g. 1. 2., 10.) at the beginning of the string and either .x or .y at the end of the string. Also, length of the `Name` variable is not the same in each row.

How can I remove the number from the beginning of the each string in the `Name` variable along with the period and the space that come after it? It's very important for me to get rid of them because I need to use the `separate` function on this data afterwards to separate into `x` and `y` from the end of the string. If I will still have that period after the number on the beginning of the string, `separate` will fail.

I wanted to use `substr` but I didn't know how to do it since, for example, `10.` is longer than `9.` and I don't know which values I would put into the `start` and `stop` arguments.

Comment: `sub("^\\d+\\. ", "", DF$Name)`

Comment: It is too basic to put it as an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: `sub("^\\d+\\.(\\s+)?", "", DF$Name)` - in case you occasionally have more than one or no space.